# Chrome memory heap is just 10 MB but the task manager shows 500 MB

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-leaks

I am using chrome's memory profiler to see the heap size. Its always around 10 MB. But my task manager's memory keeps on increasing it reaches more than 1 GB if I leave my website running. Even at this time the heap size in the profiler remains less than 10 MB. However when I close the profiler the memory in the task manager reduces to around 200 MB.

Could someone please explain why the process takes so much of memory when the actual heap size is very less.

Thanks in advance.

Dev.

This is the code:

```
updateChartData : function(priceArr, aKey, time){
    var tickData = tickDataMap[aKey+priceArr[0]];
    var price = parseFloat(priceArr[4]);
    if(tickData == undefined){
        tickData = new Array();
        tickDataMap[aKey+priceArr[0]] = tickData;
    }
    if(tickData.length > 200){
        tickData.splice(0,(tickData.length - 200));
    }
    tickData.push([time,price]);
    drawLiveTickChart(this, key);
}

function drawLiveTickChart(liveTickChart,key){
    var biddata = tickDataMap[key+'0'];
    var offerdata = tickDataMap[key+'1'];
    if(chartComponent !== null && chartComponent !== undefined){
        try {chartComponent.destroy();}catch(ex){alert("Error while drawing the tick chart : " +ex);}
        delete chartComponent;
        chartComponent = null;
    }
    chartComponent = new Highcharts.StockChart({
            chart : {
                renderTo : 'chartholder'

            },
            yAxis: {
                opposite : false
            },
            xAxis: {
                labels : {enabled:false}
            },
            plotOptions:{
                series: {
                    animation: {
                        duration: 0
                    }
                }
            },
            rangeSelector: {
                enabled : false
            },
            exporting : {
                enabled : false
            },
            navigator : {
         enabled : false,
                 height:30
             },
    scrollbar:{
        enabled : false
    },
            tooltip: {
              borderColor:"black",
              style: {
                 color: 'black'
              }
           },
            series : [{
               name : "Bid",
               data: biddata,
               color : '#008080'
            },{
                name : "Offer",
                data: offerdata,
                color : '#02D4D4'
            }
            ]
        });


}
```

Comment: Any insight into the type of code you are running in that page? Is there something looping in the page? Code samples would help.

Comment: I am drawing a chart using highstock.js whenever there is a data update. This issue is happening only with chrome. IE , firefox are working fine.

Comment: Are there a lot of 'data updates' that keep coming in?

Comment: Yes. The update frequency is almost every second.

Comment: Can you post your code that ends up looping and/or that runs when the data is updated?

Comment: You should have just edited your post to add the code. I submitted an edit you can accept and then I'd delete the 'answer' you added.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is the code :

updateChartData : function(priceArr, aKey, time){
                var tickData = tickDataMap[aKey+priceArr[0]];
                var price = parseFloat(priceArr[4]);
                if(tickData == undefined){
                    tickData = new Array();
                    tickDataMap[aKey+priceArr[0]] = tickData;
                }
                if(tickData.length > 200){
                    tickData.splice(0,(tickData.length - 200));
                }
                tickData.push([time,price]);
                drawLiveTickChart(this, key);
            }

function drawLiveTickChart(liveTickChart,key){
        var biddata = tickDataMap[key+'0'];
        var offerdata = tickDataMap[key+'1'];
        if(chartComponent !== null && chartComponent !== undefined){
            try {chartComponent.destroy();}catch(ex){alert("Error while drawing the tick chart : " +ex);}
            delete chartComponent;
            chartComponent = null;
        }
        chartComponent = new Highcharts.StockChart({
                chart : {
                    renderTo : 'chartholder'

                },
                yAxis: {
                    opposite : false
                },
                xAxis: {
                    labels : {enabled:false}
                },
                plotOptions:{
                    series: {
                        animation: {
                            duration: 0
                        }
                    }
                },
                rangeSelector: {
                    enabled : false
                },
                exporting : {
                    enabled : false
                },
                navigator : {
             enabled : false,
                     height:30
                 },
        scrollbar:{
            enabled : false
        },
                tooltip: {
                  borderColor:"black",
                  style: {
                     color: 'black'
                  }
               },
                series : [{
                   name : "Bid",
                   data: biddata,
                   color : '#008080'
                },{
                    name : "Offer",
                    data: offerdata,
                    color : '#02D4D4'
                }
                ]
            });


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code a few things stand out to me.

1. Are you intentionally setting `chartComponent` in the global context?
2. Using `delete` on a variable won't work. [From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete): "`delete` is only effective on an object's properties. It has no effect on variable or function names." Also from MDN: "Unlike what common beliefs suggests, the `delete` operator has nothing to do with directly freeing memory". I would just use the `.destroy()` method and also set `chartComponent` to null.
3. Your problem may be in how the Chrome profiler interacts with the proprietary Highcharts.StockChart library which I cannot access. Chrome could be doing all sorts of things with the data that library uses (caching `canvas` contexts, etc). The fact that you see a drop in the memory use by Chrome when you close the profiler probably means that this wouldn't happen in a normal use scenario.

### Suggestion

Try using the [`.setData()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Series.setData%28%29)  method on `chartComponent` to just update the data instead of creating a whole new chart. It is probably faster and would use less memory.